# InvokeApiAsync returning 415 on StringContent (Monodroid / Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, json, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

Using Xamarin Studio, making Xamarin.Android app with Azure Mobile Service + .NET Backend custom managed API (WebApi 2).  I know my Mobile Service is working, because I can see that my app is hitting it in the logs.  Here's the signature of my custom api:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("postplant")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPlant([FromBody] string imageInBase64)
```

I'm trying to trigger this using InvokeApiAsync, have tried a few overloads but am trying to go with the [Raw Http one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/19/custom-api-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx).  My string is a jpg that's been converted to base 64; if I input the string directly to my mobile services test site, it works fine.

My problem is, I'm getting a 415 unsupported entity media type (text/plain) error.

> Message='UserMessage='The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is
>   not supported for this resource.'', Status=415 (UnsupportedMediaType),
>   Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the
>   HTTP request resulted in an exception.

Here's my call in Xamarin:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(imageInBase64, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
HttpResponseMessage resp = await _service.InvokeApiAsync(@"jv/postplant", content, HttpMethod.Post, null, null);
```

I have also tried the following versions (and a combination of the following) defining the content-type as application/json explicitly; these hit the API OK, but the input parameter is coming through as null, so the method fails:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(imageInBase64, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage resp = await _service.InvokeApiAsync(@"jv/postplant", content, HttpMethod.Post, null, null);
```

and

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(imageInBase64, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
HttpResponseMessage resp = await _service.InvokeApiAsync(@"jv/postplant", content, HttpMethod.Post, null, null);
```

and

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(imageInBase64, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
Dictionary<string, string> reqHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
reqHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
HttpResponseMessage resp = await _service.InvokeApiAsync(@"jv/postplant", content, HttpMethod.Post, reqHeaders, null);
```

I've also tried switching up the string so it's in json (like {"imageInBase64"="xxxxlotofcharactersinbase64"}), but nothing's working.  What am I missing?

Comment: What does `InvokeApi` do?

Comment: @Cheesebaron here's the documentation from MSDN: [http://bit.ly/1UCn6LK](http://bit.ly/1UCn6LK)  It calls an API from your Azure Mobile Service; in my above example _service is an instance of [MobileServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx)

Comment: You could try inspect the traffic with Fiddler to see what is being sent just to verify where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.  The image was already in a string, but I had to serialize it like so:

```
string jObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageInBase64);
StringContent content = new StringContent(jObj, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
MediaTypeHeaderValue mValue = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType = mValue;
```

That fixed my 415 unsupported entity media type (text/plain) error; unfortunately the call was still failing on the client side, freezing at the call and never registering a response (despite my server confirming a response of 200 had been sent back).

I ultimately fixed this by removing async/await from InvokeApiAsync; either I'm not using them properly, or my app is failing when trying to await stuff.  The calls never complete.  Instead I changed these to get the Result of the async InvokeApiAsync.  Here's my solution:

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = _service.InvokeApiAsync(@"jv/postplant", content, HttpMethod.Post, null, null).Result;
_service.Dispose();

string result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JToken json = JToken.Parse(result);
return json;
```